# What does a bare line on its own do?

Tags: sbt

In a .sbt file, I often have copy-pasted lines from readmes, of which I have no idea what I'm actually doing. An example is, after adding sbt-revolver to plugins.sbt, writing the line

```
Revolver.settings
```

My current understanding of what this does is magically adding `re-start` and `re-stop` commands to sbt. I have been led to understand that a line in an .sbt file does not, in fact, perform magic, but rather creates a key and associates a value with it.

What keys does such a line set, and to what value? What would be the equivalent statement in a .scala build definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*.sbt` files can take bare [DslEntry](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.13.8/main/src/main/scala/sbt/internals/DslAst.scala#L7) which include `Setting[T]` and `Seq[Setting[T]]`.

An expression like `someString := "a"` or `someSeq += "b"` is a `Setting` for a specific `T` type.

These settings are values though, they define transformation (change, add, append, etc) of different parts of the build, which get folded into the build state and structure.

In your example `Revolver.settings` is `Seq[Setting[_]]` which defines default setup of using `sbt-revolver`.

---

If setting it up in a `project/*.scala` you need to assign it to the root project, which is either:

- the sole project in your build
- the project that aggregates all other (sub) projects.

Therefore it would look something like:

```
import sbt._, Keys._

object Build extends Build {
  val bippy = project in file(".") settings Revolver.settings
}
```

Comment: so what sbt does when it finds a bare expression for which there is an implicit to `DslEntry` is apply the setting(s) to the `settings` method on the root project and sets the returned project as the root project?

Comment: Yep, it creates a root project and applies the settings defined in `build.sbt` on it.